# Change directory to the directory of a Python script

Tags: python, scripting, directory

How do I change directory to the directory with my Python script in? So far, I figured out I should use `os.chdir` and `sys.argv[0]`. I'm sure there is a better way then to write my own function to parse argv[0].

Comment: You can directly copy-paste this: `import os; os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change directory (cd) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/608639)

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate, this question here is specific to change to the working script's dir, it's not a general question about "how to `cd` in Python"

Comment: For future reference: in the case of a cython-`--embed` .exe, `__file__` does not work. `sys.path[0]` works but it is the path of the `python38.zip` package (containing all modules) as it is usual in the case of an embedded install.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: for whatever reason __file__ was C:\dev\Python25\Lib\idlelib so a quick replace with argv[0] solved it. +1 and check marked

Comment: Also, depending on platform you may want to use `os.path.abspath` on the result of `os.path.dirname` to make sure any symbolic links or other filesystem redirection get expanded properly.

Comment: Example of case when `os.path.abspath` is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509742/change-directory-to-the-directory-of-a-python-script#comment129152389_23595382

Answer (score 17):

`os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` should do it.

`os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` would not work if the script is run from the directory in which it is present.

Comment: It also works to write `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__) or '.')`. The in-directory problem arises when `__file__` is not prefixed with `./`. `os.path.dirname` returns an empty string in that case.

Comment: Nice observation @George :)

Comment: Example of case when `os.path.abspath` is needed: you call the script on Windows from a .bat file: `python myscript.py`. Then `abspath` is mandatory.

Comment: Works, but so ugly and poorly readable!!

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes `__file__` is not defined, in this case you can try `sys.path[0]`

Comment: @Miki - when is `__file__` not defined?

Comment: @RobBednark: `python3.3 -c "print(__file__)"`

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Also true for Python 2.7.

Comment: This is true, yet irrelevant to the question, because context is outside 'Python script'.

Answer (score 2):

on windows OS, if you call something like ***python somefile.py*** this ***os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))*** will throw a WindowsError. But this should work for all cases:

```
import os
absFilePath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
os.chdir( os.path.dirname(absFilePath) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
if __name__ == "__main__": # import this_file will not change cwd
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```