# How to change default path for "save the figure" in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, path, save

I have a python code to create a figure. After showing it with `plt.show()`, I want to save the figure.
To avoid messing up the aspect ratio, resolution, etc, I do not want to use the `savefig`-command in the code. Instead, I want to use the "save the figure" button from the figure window.
However, by default, it prompts my home folder as location for the save. I would like the save to automatically be in the directory where the code was executed.
How/where can I change this window default path for saving to the current folder (or somewhere else)?

I tried this command from  [Change directory to the directory of a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509742/python-chdir-to-dir-the-py-script-is-in) at the beginning but it did not help, even though gives the filename correctly:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like you may be able to set this by changing the defaults file `matplotlibrc`, check out the guidance under http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html
where the important lines are under the savefig parameters:

```
# the default savefig params can be different from the display params

...

savefig.directory   : ~        # default directory in savefig dialog box, 
                               # leave empty to always use current working directory
```

It seems [this](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#remember-save-directory) was introduced in matplotlib 1.3. I guess you could set this using,

```
matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams["savefig.directory"] = os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

at the top of a script or by changing the `matplotlibrc` file.
For the dialog to default to cwd instead of script location (thanks to [jjcf89](https://stackoverflow.com/users/780194/jjcf89) for this)

```
matplotlib as mpl 
mpl.rcParams["savefig.directory"] = ""
```

Comment: great! now it works. I could not fix it by editing the matplotrc but then your last command helped, with the small change that I have to put: ... = "path-to-my-folder". somehow the os.chdir did not work. PS: really good to have a look at matplotrc setting. Now I can change many other things as well

Comment: Hi @physiker, glad to hear it worked. I wonder if it is even possible to set dynamic file paths of the form you wanted in the `matplotrc` file. If it's simply run like a script when matplotlib is imported, I assume you could `import os` and use something like `os.chdir`. In a script, the command `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))` should return a string which would be as valid as a hardwired "path-to-my-folder", unless I've missed something...

Comment: Hi @Ed Smith , actually "path-to-my-folder" was just " . " which is naively dynamic! I will try more with your suggestion and if I manage, i will report back. Thanks

Comment: it's important to note that `savefig.directory` is only used when clicking on the `Save` button in the interactive figure, but NOT in the script `plt.savefig('/some/path')`

Comment: Note that the following works if you want the dialog to default to cwd instead of script location.

```# Configure save dialog to use current directory```
```import matplotlib as mpl```
```mpl.rcParams["savefig.directory"] = ""```

Comment: When plotting with multiprocessing, be careful to update the parameter in the proper process. Took me some time to figure out why it did not work...

Answer (score 0):

For a non-code solution, you can create a file called `matplotlibrc` with the following contents:

```
savefig.directory:
```

This sets the value of `savefig.directory` to the empty string, causing it default to the current working directory.

You can put this `matplotlib` file in the current working directory, or in a location specified in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file). For example, on Linux it should be in `.config/matplotlib/` (don't be worried if there's no `matplotlibrc` file there already, there wasn't one on my machine either).