# cd to dir after exiting script (system independent way, purely in python)

Tags: python, shell

Observe the following:

```
$ pwd
/home/username

$ python
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("/")

# Ctrl + D
$ pwd
/home/username
```

**But I want to be in the `/` dir after exiting the python interpreter**, is that possible using python?

I would like to know because I want to make a platform independent script(using python) where an optional convenience command `cd`'s the user into a certain directory.

Comment: I do not believe this is possible in the way you intend. read this thread for more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786678/change-working-directory-in-shell-with-a-python-script

Comment: Related / possible dupe: [How do I set the working directory of the parent process?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2375003)

Comment: Hrm, I meant the other link, but it'll do.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. If you like you can put the links into a seperate answer so I can accept an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I want to be in the / dir after exiting the python interpreter, is that possible using python?

It is *not* possible. Neither by using Python or any other "acceptable" way. By acceptable, I mean "without outrageously hacking your system (with *gdb* for example)" ;)

More seriously, when the user launch an executable from a shell, the child process will run in its *own* environment, which is mostly a *copy* of its parent environment. This environment contains "environment variables" as well as the "current working directory", just to name those two.

Of course, a process can alter its environment. For example to change its working directory (like when you `cd xxx` in you shell). But since this environment is a *copy* this does not alter the parent's environment in any way. And there is no standard way to access your parent environment.