# How do you change directory in Python without creating a new instance of zsh?

Tags: python, macos, command-line, terminal, zsh

I am trying to write a program that will change the current directory in `zsh` without creating a new instance of `zsh`. Might sound confusing but what I've tried so far should help with that.

Say `zsh` is currently in the "Users" directory as in:

```
$ /Users/ →
```

If I run the following on Python:

```
os.system("cd projects")
os.system("zsh")
```

It changes `zsh` to the "Projects" directory:

```
$ /Users/ → python main.py
$ /Users/Projects/ →
```

But this creates a new instance of `zsh` and running `exit` doesn't close the Terminal window. Instead, I'll need to rerun `exit`.

Is there anyway to get Python to change current directory in `zsh` without starting up another instance of it?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to change the working directory from a child process. Check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786678/change-working-directory-in-shell-with-a-python-script

Comment: It's not changing anything in your *current* shell session; your Python script starts a new instance of `zsh`, true, but the Python script is also still running, blocking until the new `zsh` exits, at which point `os.system` returns and your Python script can continue. Also, I cannot reproduce the working directory having been changed by the code as show. The first `os.system` starts a new shell, executes the `cd` command, then that shell *exits*. The shell started by `zsh` will still have whatever working directory Python has.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're looking for the `os.chdir(path)` method bundled with Python.

You must set a new route (absolute or relative) as the `path` parameter and it will change your working path to that route.