# Python script to run Django commands

Tags: python, scripting, django-admin

I want to run a python scripts which should do:

1. Create a django project: `django-admin startproject foobar`
2. Create a app in the project: `python manage.py barfoo`
3. Add an entry of newly created app `barfoo` in the setting's `INSTALLED_APP`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read a little abour subprocess and Popen method. This might be what you're looking for.

1. `Popen(["django-admin", "startproject", "%s" % your_name ], stdout=PIPE).communicate()`
2. `Popen(["python", "manage.py", "%s" % your_app_name ], stdout=PIPE).communicate()`

3.
I know that's not a perfect code, but I'm just giving an idea.

```
with open("settings.py", 'r') as file:
    settings = file.readlines()

new_settings = []
for line in settings:
    if "INSTALLED APPS" in line:
        new_settings.append(line.replace("INSTALLED_APPS = (", "INSTALLED_APPS = (\n'%s'," % your_app_name))
    else:
        new_settings.append(line)
with open("settings.py", 'w') as file:
    file.write("".join(new_settings))
```

Comment: _Maybe_ for #1, but not for #2 or #3. Those are both easily doable in Python.

Answer (score 13):

There seems to be a pythonic way to do #1 and #2

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
management.call_command('loaddata', 'test_data', verbosity=0)
```

Answer (score 4):

6 years later I stumbled upon this question trying to figure out how to write some tests for an app which only add a custom template tag that interact with other apps in the project. Hope this can help someone.

Building on @groovehunter answer: the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code) now (Django 1.10) inculdes this feature outside dev.

Note that you need to change current directory to the created project before call `startapp`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/431715/4046810) for more details

```
from django.core import management
import os

management.call_command('startproject', 'foobar')
os.chdir('foobar')
management.call_command('startapp', 'barfoo')
```

or you can use the additional argumento to `startproject` to create the project in the current directory, if you're sure there won't be problems:

```
from django.core import management

management.call_command('startproject', 'foobar', '.')
management.call_command('startapp', 'barfoo')
```