# using python os.system for 2 process

Tags: python, svn, command, system

I want to run two commands in sequence:

1. First go to **/var/tmp/test folder**
2. Then **svn checkout** here

In order to do that I wrote this script:

```
open_folder = "cd /var/tmp/%s" % (folder_name)
cmd = "%s %s/%s/%s && %s %s/%s/%s" % (svn_co, svn_co_directory, fst_product_name, fst_firmware_name, svn_co, svn_co_directory, snd_product_name, snd_firmware_name) 
    os.system(open_folder)
    os.system(cmd)
```

It creates `folder_name`, but does not checkout into `folder_name`. It checked out to my current directory. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `os.chdir(path)` to change the directory. Or you could use the folder as a prefix in your second command. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862340/os-system-doesnt-work-in-python) explains, why `cd` won't work.

I would prefer to use `subprocess.Popen(..)` instead of os.system. It allows to specify a current working directory for the command you execute.

Comment: thanks for comment. I looked at the explanation you sent. I want to ask one more question. Do you know what is the process and subprocess ? I mean what do they differ ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question right. If you start your python program, it's execution is a process in the OS. By executing commands like `cd`, you invoke another executable. This executable runs in an own process, which is a subprocess of your python program, because you invoked it therein. I hope that answers your question. If somebody knows it better, please correct me.