# how to enter in to a folder through python code on linux

Tags: python, operating-system, scrapy

I am working on python(scrapy), i am trying to enter in to a folder by using os module but unable to do it, below is what i have tried

```
import os

scrapepath = "cd /home/local/username/project/scrapy/modulename"

os.system(scrapecmd)
```

**Result:**

```
0
```

Finally my intention is to enter in to a folder(Destination) from some where (for example home in linux) through python code as i mentioned above. Here actually i am generating some part of the path above dynamically and after that i should enter in to that path and run some commands from inside that folder

Can any one please let me know how to enter to a folder by using python code in linux as above.

Comment: why don't you want to run the command directly ? e.g., subprocess.call(["/path/to/my/command", "arg1", "arg2"])

Comment: @JohnWang: There are certainly plenty of programs out there where the working directory is relevant to behavior.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python

Comment: i am working on scrapy actually, i dont want to run command directly because i will create number of scrapy folder which consists of individual spider names each, so need to enter in to each folder and need to run command through that spider name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the current working directory:

```
os.chdir("/home/local/username/project/scrapy/modulename")
```

You might also like to simply add that module to python's path (which is where `import` looks):

```
sys.path.append("/home/local/username/project/scrapy/modulename")
```

Comment: As an addition- the reason that `os.system` doesn't work in the original question, is that `os.system` creates a new process - changes the directory __in that process__ and then closes the process.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
import os

os.chdir("/home/local/username/project/scrapy/modulename")
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, os.system() executes the string command in a subshell. So, when you execute something like:

```
os.system("cd /path/to/directory/")
```

The `cd` command will actually be executed in a subshell. But, as the subshell exits after `os.system` execution, your `cd` has no practical effect for your application.

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.python.org/library/os.html

```
import os
os.chdir(path)
```