# How to use the context manager to avoid the use of __del__ in python?

Tags: python, contextmanager

As it is common knowledge, the python `__del__` method should not be used to clean up important things, as it is not guaranteed this method gets called. The alternative is the use of a context manager, as described in several threads.

But I do not quite understand how to rewrite a class to use a context manager. To elaborate, I have a simple (non-working) example in which a wrapper class opens and closes a device, and which shall close the device in any case the instance of the class gets out of its scope (exception etc).

The first file `mydevice.py` is a standard wrapper class to open and close a device:

```
class MyWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def open(self):
        self.device.open()

    def close(self):
        self.device.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.close()
```

this class is used by another class `myclass.py`:

```
import mydevice


class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self, device):

        # calls open in mydevice
        self.mydevice = mydevice.MyWrapper(device)
        self.mydevice.open()

    def processing(self, value):
        if not value:
            self.mydevice.close()
        else:
            something_else()
```

My question: When I implement the context manager in `mydevice.py` with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, how can this class be handled in `myclass.py`? I need to do something like

```
def __init__(self, device):
    with mydevice.MyWrapper(device):
        ???
```

but how to handle it then? Maybe I overlooked something important? Or can I use a context manager only within a function and not as a variable inside a class scope?

Answer (score 18):

I suggest using the contextlib.contextmanager class instead of writing a class that implements `__enter__` and `__exit__`.  Here's how it would work:

```
class MyWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device

    def open(self):
        self.device.open()

    def close(self):
        self.device.close()

    # I assume your device has a blink command
    def blink(self):
        # do something useful with self.device
        self.device.send_command(CMD_BLINK, 100)

    # there is no __del__ method, as long as you conscientiously use the wrapper

import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_device(device):
    wrapper_object = MyWrapper(device)
    wrapper_object.open()
    try:
        yield wrapper_object
    finally:
        wrapper_object.close()
    return

with open_device(device) as wrapper_object:
     # do something useful with wrapper_object
     wrapper_object.blink()
```

The line that starts with an at sign is called a *decorator*.  It modifies the function declaration on the next line.

When the `with` statement is encountered, the `open_device()` function will execute up to the `yield` statement.  The value in the `yield` statement is returned in the variable that's the target of the optional `as` clause, in this case, `wrapper_object`.  You can use that value like a normal Python object thereafter.  When control exits from the block by *any* path – including throwing exceptions – the remaining body of the `open_device` function will execute.

I'm not sure if (a) your wrapper class is adding functionality to a lower-level API, or (b) if it's only something you're including so you can have a context manager.  If (b), then you can probably dispense with it entirely, since contextlib takes care of that for you.  Here's what your code might look like then:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_device(device):
    device.open()
    try:
        yield device
    finally:
        device.close()
    return

with open_device(device) as device:
     # do something useful with device
     device.send_command(CMD_BLINK, 100)
```

99% of context manager uses can be done with contextlib.contextmanager.  It is an extremely useful API class (and the way it's implemented is also a creative use of lower-level Python plumbing, if you care about such things).

Comment: Is the return needed in `def open_device` ?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is not that you're using it in a class, it's that you want to leave the device in an "open-ended" way: you open it and then just leave it open.  A context manager provides a way to open some resource and use it in a relatively short, contained way, making sure it is closed at the end.  Your existing code is already unsafe, because if some crash occurs, you can't guarantee that your `__del__` will be called, so the device may be left open.

Without knowing exactly what the device is and how it works, it's hard to say more, but the basic idea is that, if possible, it's better to only open the device right when you need to use it, and then close it immediately afterwards.  So your `processing` is what might need to change, to something more like:

```
def processing(self, value):
     with self.device:
        if value:
            something_else()
```

If `self.device` is an appropriately-written context manager, it should open the device in `__enter__` and close it in `__exit__`.  This ensures that the device will be closed at the end of the `with` block.

Of course, for some sorts of resources, it's not possible to do this (e.g., because opening and closing the device loses important state, or is a slow operation).  If that is your case, you are stuck with using `__del__` and living with its pitfalls.  The basic problem is that there is no foolproof way to leave the device "open-ended" but still guarantee it will be closed even in the event of some unusual program failure.

Comment: Same comment as before: I do not know beforehand what happens to the device, but it will be opened and used in several other methods, classes etc. Is that a case I should still use `__del__` instead?

Comment: I think `__del__()` is your only open for this open-ended behaviour. Bear in mind that `__del__()` is only not called if the garbage collector finds a reference cycle involving your class. You can even detect and resolve this manually in your code by periodically checking [`gc.garbage`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.garbage) and breaking the reference cycles that are causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. A context manager instance can be a class member - you can re-use it in as many `with` clauses as you like and the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods will be called each time.

So, once you'd added those methods to `MyWrapper`, you can construct it in `MyClass` just as you are above. And then you'd do something like:

```
def my_method(self):
    with self.mydevice:
        # Do stuff here
```

That will call the `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` methods on the instance you created in the constructor.

However, the `with` clause can only span a function - if you use the `with` clause in the constructor then it will call `__exit__()` before exiting the constructor. If you want to do that, the only way is to use `__del__()`, which has its own problems as you've already mentioned. You could open and close the device just when you need it using `with` but I don't know if this fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Your solution also works only within one function! What if I want to open something in the method `my_method()`, do something else in a different function? The your suggestion won't work.

Comment: As I pointed out at the end of my answer, the `with` clause will only work within the function in which it's used - that's just the way it's defined. You could use `with` in the class definition but it would only apply while the definition was being processed. If you want the same effect across the lifetime of a class then you'll need to use `__del__()`, even though it suffers from problems. The better solution is probably to only open and close the device in each function. Sorry if I didn't make that clear enough.