# Why does my contextmanager-function not work like my contextmanager class in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, contextmanager

In my code, I need to be able to open and close a device properly, and therefore see the need to use a context manager. While a context manager is usually defined as a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, there also seem to be the possibility to decorate a function for use with the context manager (see [a recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427361/how-to-use-the-context-manager-to-avoid-the-use-of-del-in-python/15427892?noredirect=1#15427892) and [another nice example here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example)).

In the following (working) code snippet, I have implemented the two possibilities; one just need to swap the commented line with the other one:

```
import time
import contextlib

def device():
    return 42

@contextlib.contextmanager
def wrap():
    print("open")
    yield device
    print("close")
    return

class Wrap(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print("open")
        return device
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print("close")


#with wrap() as mydevice:
with Wrap() as mydevice:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print mydevice()
```

What I try is to run the code and stop it with `CTRL-C`. When I use the `Wrap` class in the context manager, the `__exit__` method is called as expeced (the text 'close' is printed in the terminal), but when I try the same thing with the `wrap` function, the text 'close' is not printed to the terminal.

My question: Is there a problem with the code snippet, am I missing something, or why is the line `print("close")` not called with the decorated function?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example in the documentation for `contextmanager` is somewhat misleading.  The portion of the function after `yield` does not really correspond to the `__exit__` of the context manager protocol.  The key point in the documentation is this:

> If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred. Thus, you can use a `try...except...finally` statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place.

So if you want to handle an exception in your contextmanager-decorated function, you need to write your own `try` that wraps the `yield` and handle the exceptions yourself, executing cleanup code in a `finally` (or just block the exception in `except` and execute your cleanup after the `try/except`).  For example:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def cm():
    print "before"
    exc = None
    try:
        yield
    except Exception, exc:
        print "Exception was caught"
    print "after"
    if exc is not None:
        raise exc

>>> with cm():
...     print "Hi!"
before
Hi!
after

>>> with cm():
...     print "Hi!"
...     1/0
before
Hi!
Exception was caught
after
```

[This page](http://pymotw.com/2/contextlib/index.html#from-generator-to-context-manager) also shows an instructive example.