# Python - Exception seems to be skipping out of with block

Tags: python, with-statement, contextmanager

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def make_temp_dir():
      temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
      yield temp_dir
      shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)

    with make_temp_dir(listing_id) as tmpdir:
      pass
      # Sometimes something in here throws an exception that gets caught higher up
```

Ok, so writing this all out, I understand now what's happening. The **exit** method in the contextmanager I'm creating with the decorator *is* running but that doesn't, of course, return flow to my generator.

So how *should* I be doing this?

Comment: If you want to catch an exception in the contextmanager, you need to write a `try`/`except` as usual.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447130/why-does-my-contextmanager-function-not-work-like-my-contextmanager-class-in-pyt).

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is the following:

- On `__enter__()`, the generator is started. What it yields is taken for return value of `__enter__()`.
- On `__exit__()`, the generator is resumed, either in a normal way or by injecting an exception. The relevant code is in `$PYTHONROOT/contextlib.py` where you can see that either `next()` or `throw()` is called on the generator.

If `throw()` is called on a generator, the exception is raised inside it exactly where we left it the last time, i. e. the `yield` expression raises the exception then.

Thus, you will have to enclose the `yield` in a `try:` statement. Only then, you'll be able to do something with the exception.

If you fail to do so, your generator will raise the exception back without doing anything.

You probably want

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def make_temp_dir():
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        yield temp_dir
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

Comment: Thanks. So this excepting is being re-raised inside my generator, right? I guess what I'm getting at is, this exception will still be handled by existing `except` that's outside my `with`? So it works like.. exception is raised.. __exit__() is called, passing the exception to throw(), and then the exception is handled by my outer `except`? 

Thanks

Comment: @ShaneH Yes, but it is not really "outer". The `with` statement is kind of mapped to the `try...finally` inside the generator.