# Excel doesn't close if I use the "with" keyword instead of "inline" python

Tags: python, excel, excel-interop

I use python to refresh some power query table in Excel using win32com.client library.

- If I write everything "inline" (1st version): excel closes correctly
- If I use a "with" statement to open/close excel and workbooks (2nd version): excel process doesn't close

---

==> Why is it not doing the same thing?

==> How can I make the "with" version working?

**Code "inline" : excel closes correctly:**

```
# Start excel app
xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xlapp.Visible = False
xlapp.Interactive = False
excel_constant = win32.constants

# Open workbook
file_name = str(file)
wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(file_name)

#Refresh power query
wb.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()

# Close workbook
wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
wb = None
gc.collect()

# Quit excel app
xlapp.Quit()
xlapp = None
gc.collect()
```

**Using "with" the excel process stays active**

```
class start_excel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        self.xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        self.xlapp.Visible = False
        self.xlapp.Interactive = False

        return self.xlapp

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.xlapp.Quit()
        self.xlapp = None
        gc.collect()


class open_workbook(object):
    def __init__(self, xlapp, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.xlapp = xlapp
     
    def __enter__(self):
        self.chemin_fichier = str(self.file_name)
        self.wb = self.xlapp.Workbooks.Open(self.chemin_fichier)
        
        return self.wb
 
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        self.wb = None
        gc.collect()



with start_excel() as xlapp:
    # excel_constant = win32.constants
    with open_workbook(xlapp, file) as wb:
        wb.RefreshAll()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
```

**EDIT: 3rd example, with a contextlib.contextmanager (same issue)**

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def start_excel():
    try:
        xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        xlapp.Visible = False
        xlapp.Interactive = False
        yield xlapp

    finally:
        xlapp.Quit()
        xlapp = None
        gc.collect()

@contextlib.contextmanager
def open_workbook(xlapp, file_name):
    try:
        chemin_fichier = str(file_name)
        wb = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(chemin_fichier)
        yield wb
    
    finally:
        wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        wb = None
        gc.collect()



with start_excel() as xlapp:
    # excel_constant = win32.constants
    with open_workbook(xlapp, file) as wb:
        wb.RefreshAll()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
```

**EDIT: code below works but is not satisfying**
I added the 2 last lines: `wb = None` & `xlapp = None`, Excel closes correctly.
But it doesn't feel safe, is there a way to ensure that the with statement cleanly clear its variables? I feel like it's easy to forget to include these additionnal lines every time I use with.

```
class start_excel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        self.xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        self.xlapp.Visible = False
        self.xlapp.Interactive = False

        return self.xlapp

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.xlapp.Quit()
        self.xlapp = None
        gc.collect()


class open_workbook(object):
    def __init__(self, xlapp, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.xlapp = xlapp
     
    def __enter__(self):
        self.chemin_fichier = str(self.file_name)
        self.wb = self.xlapp.Workbooks.Open(self.chemin_fichier)
        
        return self.wb
 
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        self.wb = None
        gc.collect()



with start_excel() as xlapp:
    # excel_constant = win32.constants
    with open_workbook(xlapp, file) as wb:
        wb.RefreshAll()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        wb = None
    
    xlapp = None
```

Comment: You have to define your own context manager - try to search "python context manager" on google.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my contextmanager-function not work like my contextmanager class in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447130/why-does-my-contextmanager-function-not-work-like-my-contextmanager-class-in-pyt)

Comment: No, it does not: 
 - I understand that using '''__enter__''' and '''__exit__''' is already the right way to do it
 - I'll add an example with "@contextlib.contextmanager" but it has the same issue

Comment: I think I found the issue, but i'm not sure what is the best practice: "with" statement does not create a scope, therefore wb and xlapp are not cleanly set to None when the with Statement is closed. / However, it means that I need to add some code outside of the context manager to cleanly close excel. Is there a way to keep it in the contextmanager in order to be sure it closes? / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45100271/scope-of-variable-within-with-statement /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the issue:

- Excel needs the variable set to None so it can close
- Using with keyword, there are 2 references : the reference in the generator and the one in the "main" code. the `__exit__` part remove only one of the 2 references.

The last version works as expected, but I don't like that you need to do some mandatory clean up outside of the `__exit__` part.

```
class start_excel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        self.xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        self.xlapp.Visible = False
        self.xlapp.Interactive = False

        return self.xlapp

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.xlapp.Quit()
        self.xlapp = None
        gc.collect()


class open_workbook(object):
    def __init__(self, xlapp, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.xlapp = xlapp
     
    def __enter__(self):
        self.chemin_fichier = str(self.file_name)
        self.wb = self.xlapp.Workbooks.Open(self.chemin_fichier)
        
        return self.wb
 
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        self.wb = None
        gc.collect()



with start_excel() as xlapp:
    # excel_constant = win32.constants
    with open_workbook(xlapp, file) as wb:
        wb.RefreshAll()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        wb = None
    
    xlapp = None
```