# Python: clean way to set variable to None when not used anymore?

Tags: python, excel-interop

Using excel from Python require to set all references to workbooks & excel app to None at the end to be sure it closes (using the API win32com.client).

At first I expected to be able to use the `with` keyword and include all the "clean up" code in the `__exit__()` function. But I still have references that needs to be cleaned up when I do it this way...

==> Is it possible to do it in a better way? Better = all the clean up code in packaged in the **exit**() function. (not using contextmanager has the same issue: [Excel doesn't close if I use the "with" keyword instead of "inline" python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021839/excel-doesnt-close-if-i-use-the-with-keyword-instead-of-inline-python/75054526#75054526) )

example: I have to set wb & xlapp to `None` outside for the `__exit__()` function

```
class start_excel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        self.xlapp = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        self.xlapp.Visible = False
        self.xlapp.Interactive = False

        return self.xlapp

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.xlapp.Quit()
        self.xlapp = None
        gc.collect()




class open_workbook(object):
    def __init__(self, xlapp, file_name):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.xlapp = xlapp
     
    def __enter__(self):
        self.chemin_fichier = str(self.file_name)
        self.wb = self.xlapp.Workbooks.Open(self.chemin_fichier)
        
        return self.wb
 
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.wb.Close(SaveChanges=True)
        self.wb = None
        gc.collect()



with start_excel() as xlapp:
    # excel_constant = win32.constants
    with open_workbook(xlapp, file) as wb:
        wb.RefreshAll()
        xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
        wb = None
    
    xlapp = None
```

thanks

Comment: Try `del wb` and `del xlapp`. Assigning `None` doesn't remove references I think.

Comment: `wb = None` and `xlapp = None` works, however, it's not safe. If I forget to do it when I use `with`, then it won't close excel. I'd like the `__exit__()` function to do 100% of the clean up.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this [link](https://pythonexcels.com/python/2009/10/05/python-excel-mini-cookbook#open-excel-add-a-workbook), you can call `xlapp.Application.Quit()`

Comment: I replaced `xlapp.Quit()` by `xlapp.Application.Quit()` and removed `xlapp = None`: it didn't close excel. I understand I really need to remove all references to xlapp to be sure that excel closes.