# Set all reference to None using "with"?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I try to use the context manager to have all the clean up code in the `finally:` part of my fonction.

- One goal of the clean up is to make sure that all references to the class `initialize_stuff()` are set to None.
- using the code below, there is still an active reference to the `initialize_stuff()` at the end
- I can "force" the variable to None, but I may forget it when I use the context manager, I expect the context manager to do it.

Is it possible? How?

Notes:

- using `__enter__()` and `__exit__()` has the same issue
- The full problem I'm trying to solve (it's a simplified version here): [Excel doesn't close if I use the "with" keyword instead of "inline" python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75021839/excel-doesnt-close-if-i-use-the-with-keyword-instead-of-inline-python)

```
import contextlib
import gc

class initialize_stuff(object):
    def use(self):
        pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def do_things():
    try:
        release_me = initialize_stuff()
        yield release_me 
    
    finally:
        release_me = None
        gc.collect()


with do_things() as release_me:
    release_me.use()
    # release_me = None
    
if release_me is not None:
    print("release_me is not released")
else:
    print("yeah")
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I understand why there is still a reference to initialize_stuff(), but i'm not sure how to make a "cleaner" version where the `finally:` part does the clean up

Comment: Short of returning a [`weakref`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/weakref.html), so the reference held by `release_me` isn't included in the underlying object's reference count, you can't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer, not sure if it's a "clean" one:
I use an object in-between the call and the target class. This way, only the object in-between keep the "real" reference and it can be set to None in the context manager.

Added: `send_to_class`

```
import contextlib
import gc


class send_to_class(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr): # récupère les appels sur des méthodes non connues
        return getattr(self.item, attr)

class initialize_stuff(object):
    def use(self):
        pass

@contextlib.contextmanager
def do_things():
    try:
        release_me = send_to_class(initialize_stuff())
        yield release_me 
    
    finally:
        release_me.item = None
        gc.collect()


with do_things() as release_me:
    release_me.use()
    
if release_me is not None:
    print("release_me is not released")
else:
    print("yeah")
```