# Running a script in another directory

Tags: python

Currently, I have created a code that makes graphs from data in .csv files. However, I can only run the code if that code is present in the folder with the csv files. How can I make the the script file so that it doesn't have to be in the same directory as the .csv files. Also, I would like that same script to read every csv file in that other directory.

This is what I was using before:

```
directory = ""
listing = os.listdir(directory)
for files in listing:
   if files.endswith('.csv'):  
        df=pd.read_csv(files)
```

Comment: Google for "python change directory" yields [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `directory = ""` with `directory="../your-path-to-csv-files"`. Here is a complete example:

```
directory = "../your-path-to-csv-files"
listing = os.listdir(directory)
for files in listing:
   if files.endswith('.csv'):  
        full_name = os.path.join(directory,files)
        df=pd.read_csv(full_name)
```

Comment: thats what I have right now, i just didnt specify the path in the description.

Comment: See edit, you need to get the full name by using `os.path.join`

Answer (score 0):

I've built for such purposes a little function, which calculates paths of data relative to the execution-place of the python-file:

```
import os
def getPathToData():
    path = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path = os.path.abspath(path[0])
    path = path + "/data/"
    return path
```

Maybe this snippet can help you.