# Do a maven build in a python script

Tags: python, maven, python-2.7, build

I am checking out a source for a given url using a python script and I want to go to the downloadedFoler/src directory and perform a `mvn clean install`. I want to do it in the same script. Thank in advance.

Comment: I tried os.system("mvn clean install") and it works but I need to perform this in the correct location.

Comment: Try this question: [how-do-i-cd-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python)

Comment: You have to go into the location where pom.xml file is located which mean in your case a level higher.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
import os
import subprocess

# Context Manager to change current directory.
# I looked at this implementation on stackoverflow but unfortunately do not have the link
# to credit the user who wrote this part of the code.
class changeDir:
  def __init__(self, newPath):
    self.newPath = os.path.expanduser(newPath)

  # Change directory with the new path
  def __enter__(self):
    self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(self.newPath)

  # Return back to previous directory
  def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
    os.chdir(self.savedPath)

# folderPath = path of the folder you want to run mvn clean install on
with changeDir(folderPath):
  # ****** NOTE ******: using shell=True is strongly discouraged since it possesses security risks
  subprocess.call(["mvn", "clean", "install"], shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a recent Python (3.11+), there is [`contextmanager.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.chdir) which can be used to conveniently switch the current directory. This already behaves like the context manager that @SaurabhM's answer implements.

Alternatively, it is possible to run a subprocess with a specific directory that is set as the current directory for the child process. This is in general preferable than changing the working directory of your own program, because changing directory affects the entire process, including all the threads it might have created. This is not much of an issue for small scripts, but it becomes hard to manage at scale.

When you specify arguments to run in a list, it is not necessary to use shell to do any further parsing or evaluation, so you can set `shell=False` (which is the default).

Use [`subprocess.check_call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) for the conveniences provided by it.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['mvn', 'clean', 'install'], cwd=folderPath)
```