# sh.cd using context manager

Tags: python, shell, contextmanager

here is what I am basically trying to do:

```
import sh, os

with sh.cd('/tmp'):
  print os.getcwd()

print os.getcwd()
```

I get the following error though

```
line 3, in <module>
    with sh.cd('/tmp'):
AttributeError: __exit__
```

What am I missing here? Are there alternative solutions to change directory within a context?

Comment: There's a good solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13197763/1901786).

Comment: thx, @whereswalden. I have done some research before, and stumbled over that answer as well. But I wonder whether there is no "short" solution. This seems like a frequent use-case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use just any class/function as a context manager, it has to actually explicitly be implemented that way, using either the [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) decorator on a function, or in the case of a class, by defining the [`__enter__` and `__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) instance methods.

The `sh.cd` function you're using is simply a wrapper around `os.chdir`:

```
>>> import sh
>>> sh.cd
<bound method Environment.b_cd of {}>
```

`b_cd` is defined as:

```
def b_cd(self, path):
    os.chdir(path)
```

As you can see, it's just a normal function; it can't be used as a context manager.

The link whereswalden provided shows a good way of implementing the behavior you want as a class. It could similarly be implemented as a function like this:

```
import contextlib
import os

@contextlib.contextmanager
def cd(path):
   old_path = os.getcwd()
   os.chdir(path)
   try:
       yield
   finally:
       os.chdir(old_path)
```

Sample usage:

```
print(os.getcwd())
with cd("/"):
    print os.getcwd()
print(os.getcwd())
```

Output:

```
'/home/dan'
'/'
'/home/dan'
```

Answer (score 3):

`sh` now has the `pushd()` function that can be used as a context manager to change the current directory temporarily:

```py
import sh

with sh.pushd("/tmp"):
    sh.touch("a_file")
```

See https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/command_class.html?highlight=pushd#pushd