# subprocess not working with change directory in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I'm doing this simple thing

```
import subprocess
with cd("/home/myuserid"):
  subprocess.call("ls ")
```

where cd is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python) and it just does not work (same with any other path):

> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: You mean this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13197763/1221660

Comment: in which line do you get that error? cd or subprocess.call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra space after `ls`, which is causing your issue. Remove that and it should work fine.

```
import subprocess
with cd("/home/myuserid"):
    subprocess.call("ls")
```

When you use `subprocess` without `shell=True`, it interprets the entire string you pass as the command to execute. So it looks for a program literally called `"ls "` when you provide that extra space, which of course doesn't exist.

If you were to use `shell=True`, it would work fine even with the extra space, because a `/bin/sh` shell would be used to run the command, and the shell wouldn't care about the extra space. In general it's safer to use the default of `shell=False`, though, so I'd stick with that.