# Python: Changing terminal current directory and calling script

Tags: python, bash, terminal

Once i check a particular file is there in a folder, i want to call bash script titled    `nii-sdcme`    from python. But before calling this script in terminal, i want to cd to particular directory. Can this be done in python?

So steps to run this script in terminal looks like this:

```
cd DICOM/  
nii_sdcme N
```

Where N is some folderNumber. eg: 92

```
cd DICOM/  
nii_sdcme 92
```

Can some one please direct me how this can be implemented in python script?

Many Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "cd" in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python)

Comment: How are you planning to run your shell script from python? Do you want to change to that directory for the whole python script or just the shell script?

Comment: @EtanReisner Just the shell script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way would be using [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Current dir: %s" % os.getcwd()
    os.chdir('/tmp/')
    print "Current dir: %s" % os.getcwd()
```

Which outputs when called:

```
Current dir: /home/borrajax/Documents/Tests/StackOverflow
Current dir: /tmp
```

Now, you mentioned that you want to call a particular script (`nii-sdcme`) within your script. You are probably going to use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to do that. With the tools provided by the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module, you can specify a `cwd` argument so the script (executable, rather) called *"sees"* that `cwd` path as its run directory. Be aware that this sets the directory indicated in `cwd` *after* the executable is called... what I mean by this is that `Popen` needs to find the executable's path *before* setting the executable's run directory. Let's say you're in your `/home/` and the `nii-sdcme` script is located in `/tmp/`.

This:

```
subprocess.Popen(['nii-sdcme'], cwd='/tmp/')
```

will fail, because the executable is not in the directories defined in the `$PATH` environment variable. On the other hand, this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['/tmp/nii-sdcme'], cwd='/tmp/')
```

will succeed.

From the [subrprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) docs:

> If cwd is not None, the child’s current directory will be changed to
>   cwd before it is executed. Note that this directory is not considered
>   when searching the executable, so **you can’t specify the program’s
>   path relative to cwd.**

**EDIT** (As per OP's comment to this question)

> how about if i change os.chdir(desired/path) and then cann
>   subprocess.call('nii_sdcme %s' %a)

That'll make `nii_sdcme` use `desired/path` as run directory as well. `os.chdir` changes the path of the current process (your current interpreter). If you subsequently call your `nii_sdcme` executable without specifying a `cwd` argument, the spawned subprocess will use as current directory the current directory of the parent process.

(!) Careful: Even if you change the current directory of your executable through `os.chdir`, you still need to provide the full path to your `nii_sdcme` executable (unless `nii_sdcme` is in one of the directories specified in the `$PATH` environment variable)

Comment: how about if i do this     os.chdir(desired/path) and then call subprocess.call('nii_sdcme %s' %a)

Comment: Glad I helped. :-) Have fun coding!!

Comment: :I tried the following syntax and been getting following error:      os.chdir('/dicom/1013/0007')
subprocess.Popen(['nii_mdir_sdcme %s %s' %a %s])                   "Error:TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"   Can you please help me this..?

Comment: @tryeverylanguage: That's probably another question, but you're trying to create a formatted string without telling it what to format: This is good: `print ("Hello: %s %s" % ('world', 7))"` but if the string is expecting 2 "%s" and you only pass one, then you get that error:  `print ("Hello: %s %s" % (7))"`