# How to pass string as variable in Python?

Tags: python

I used Context Manager: cd from here: [How do I "cd" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python/13197763#13197763)

```
import os

class cd:
    """Context manager for changing the current working directory"""
    def __init__(self, newPath):
        self.newPath = os.path.expanduser(newPath)

    def __enter__(self):
        self.savedPath = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.newPath)

    def __exit__(self, etype, value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.savedPath)
```

Example

```
import subprocess # just to call an arbitrary command e.g. 'ls'

# enter the directory like this:
with cd("~/Library"):
   # we are in ~/Library
   subprocess.call("ls")

# outside the context manager we are back wherever we started.
```

Why not work this code if I use like this:

```
str = "~/Library"

with cd(str):
   subprocess.call("ls")
```

Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cd ~/Library'
```

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? It should work fine.

Comment: Try renaming `str` to something that doesn't collide with built-in names.

Comment: Please, reformat your code to indicate that `__enter__` and `__exit__` are methods within class, not just functions.

Comment: Sorry, I missed error message.. I renamed str to cd_path but it still not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code seems to work as it should. I can only duplicate your error if I added 'cd' to the value of `str` such that it tried to change to a directory called 'cd ~/Library'. That is also what seems to have happened based on the error message you show.

Broken

```
str = "cd ~/Library"
with cd(str):
   subprocess.call("ls")
```

Fine

```
str = "~/Library"
with cd(str):
   subprocess.call("ls")
```

Comment: You are right, I leave 'cd' right there, I should have copy my own code..