# Python script to change dir for user

Tags: python, shell, cd

I am trying to create Python script `jump.py` that allows me to jump to a set of predefined dirs, and looks like it is not possible to do this, because after scripts exits, the previous directory is restored:

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('..')
print(os.getcwd())
```

---

```
[micro]$ python jump.py 
/home/iset/go/src/github.com/zyedidia/micro
/home/iset/go/src/github.com/zyedidia
[micro]$
```

Is that at all possible to land to `[zyedidia]` dir after the script finishes?

Comment: See [this horrible hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python)...., the answer is at the bottom with 5 votes (as of today)

Comment: Is it mandatory to use Python for your task ?

Comment: @SimonPA I'd like to keep that cross-platform if possible and not requiring compilation.

Comment: Alright, it's tricky to achieve that because the Python interpreter will always restore the property of the shell at the start of the process. I see in your exemple that you use your script in a Git repository. Is it meant to be use in Git hooks ? If yes, We might be able to find a workaround there

Comment: @576i horrible hack is not a horrible answer. =)

Comment: @SimonPA it is meant to quickly jump between different upstream projects from command line. Previously I would just stack every projects under `~/p`, but [golang] ruins the workflow, which is inconvenient anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir('..')
print(os.getcwd())
shell = os.environ.get('SHELL', '/bin/sh')
os.execl(shell, shell)
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid executing subshells to avoid both `cd` and `shell process` stack overflow.