# Python subprocess not navigating venv folder

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm attempting to automate some of the steps I routinely go through in setting up `venv` environments in Python. I'm able to get to where I create the folder and a `requirements.txt` folder inside, containing any modules I desire. But it seems like the session doesn't remember the last command, preventing me from activating the `venv` and installing the `requirements.txt` file afterwards.

```
# Navigate to new venv directory
subprocess.run("cd " + destination, shell=True)
# Activate venv environment.
subprocess.run("Scripts\\activate.bat", shell=True)
# Install requirements with pip.
subprocess.run("pip install -r requirements.txt", shell=True)
```

> **Output:**
>
> `The system cannot find the path specified.`
>
> `Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`

Comment: Umm... shouldn't you be using [`os.chdir`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/5067311) instead? Subprocess should spawn...well, a subprocess, which indeed shouldn't change the state of the calling script.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Feel free to throw an example in the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of navigating to the folder and attempting to install with `pip`, I called `pip` inside the `venv` Scripts folder and installed the packages which were already appended to a list when I was writing to `requirements.txt`.

```
# Install requirements to venv.
subprocess.run([os.path.join(destination, 'Scripts', 'pip.exe')] + 'install {}'.format(' '.join(requirements)).split())
```

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to the folder with requirements.txt after activating env, this file definitely not in the environment folder.

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean, but `requirements.txt` absolutely is in the venv folder. Inside, there is `Include`, `Lib`, `Scripts` and `requirements.txt`. That much of the script works without fail.

Comment: So you created virtualenv, after that went into it put requirements.txt inside?

Comment: Once the `venv` folder is created, the requirements.txt is created and populated, yes. The parts after this are where I'm having issues.