# Creating files from a Python script within a shell script within a shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7, shell

I'm trying to run a Python script from a shell script within a shell script, but I'm running into some problems.

Imagine my root shell script looks like this:

```
echo "test0"
sh ./test/test1/test2.sh
```

and my test2.sh:

```
echo "test2"
python testme.py
```

The python file is in the same directory as `test2.sh` but test2.sh's working directory seems to be the root's so it cannot find the python script. So, if I give the python script's absolute location to `test2.sh`, the python file runs, but when the python file creates new files, it's created in the root.

If there is a solution so that I don't have to edit the python script to create new files in the directory of the python script, please let me know.

Comment: do this in test2.sh `echo \`pwd\`` and comment here the output

Comment: It's the same pwd as the root shell script's

Comment: Then do `cd /som/path/test/test1/test2` in test2.sh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "cd" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your root script:

```
echo "test0"
cd test/test1
sh ./test2.sh
```

Your script test2 is launched with the environment of your root script. So you just have to cd in your root script.