# In subprocess, some commands work but not others from Mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, popen

I am trying to create a python script that runs a perl script on the Mac terminal. The popular 3D printer slicing engine, Slic3r, has the ability to use command line usage, which is written in Perl. I want to write a python script to automate some processes, which is the language I know best. If I type the commands I want to use directly into the terminal, it works as it should, however, if I try to use python's `subprocess`, it works for some commands but not others.

For example if I use my script to fetch the Slic3r version using the syntax outlined in the [docs](http://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/command-line), it works correctly. This script works:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system("cd Slic3r")

perl = "perl"
perl_script = "/Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl"
params = "--version"

pl_script = subprocess.Popen([perl, perl_script, params], stdout=sys.stdout)
pl_script.communicate()

print 'done'
```

This returns:

```
1.3.0-dev
done
```

If I use a command such as --info (see Slic3r docs under repairing models for more info) using the same script I get:

In:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system("cd Slic3r")

perl = "perl"
perl_script = "/Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl"
params = "--info /Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl"

pl_script = subprocess.Popen([perl, perl_script, params], stdout=sys.stdout)
pl_script.communicate()

print 'done'
```

Out:

```
Unknown option: info /Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl
Slic3r 1.3.0-dev is a STL-to-GCODE translator for RepRap 3D printers
written by Alessandro Ranellucci <aar@cpan.org> - http://slic3r.org/

Usage: slic3r.pl [ OPTIONS ] [ file.stl ] [ file2.stl ] ...
```

From what I have researched, I suspect that there is some issue with the whitespace of a string being used as a argument. I have never used `subprocess` until attempting this project, so a simple syntax error could be likely.

I know that the Slic3r syntax is correct because it works perfectly if I type it directly into the terminal. Can anybody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're doing the equivalent of the shell command `'perl' 'slic3r.pl' '--info GEAR.stl'` instead of `'perl' 'slic3r.pl' '--info' 'GEAR.stl'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) accepts `args` as the first parameter. This can be ***either a string*** with the complete command (including parameters):

```
args = "perl /Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl --info /Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl"
pl_script = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=sys.stdout)
```

***or a list*** consisting of the actual command and all its parameters (the actual command in your case is `perl`):

```
args = ["perl", 
        "/Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl", 
        "--info", 
        "/Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl"]
pl_script = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=sys.stdout)
```

The latter is preferred because it bypasses the shell and directly executes `perl`. From the docs:

> `args` should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single
>   string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in `args`
>   if `args` is a sequence. If `args` is a string, the interpretation is
>   platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable
>   arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless
>   otherwise stated, **it is recommended to pass `args` as a sequence**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

The `args` list may of course be built with Python's standard list operations:

```
base_args = ["perl", 
             "/Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl"]
options   = ["--info", 
             "/Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl"]
args = base_args + options
args.append("--verbose")
pl_script = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=sys.stdout)
```

---

***Sidenote***: You wrote `os.system("cd Slic3r")`. This will open a shell, change the directory *in that shell*, and then exit. Your Python script will still operate in the original working directory. To change it, use `os.chdir("Slic3r")` instead. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/5830574).)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you! An additional question I have being this worked: Since args is a list, if I wanted to add, modify, etc. can standard list modifiers such as append be used without it messing up the format?

Comment: @paperstsoap Sure. `args` is just a list. You can modify it with standard list operations. Just make sure the first element is `perl` and the second is your script. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **shlex** to break down the complex arguments expecially in mac or unix

more information here 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html#shlex.split

e.g.

```
import shlex, subprocess
args = "perl /Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl --info /Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl"

#using shlex to break down the arguments 

mac_arg=shlex.split(args)

#shlex.split will return all the arguments in a list
```

output

```
['perl', '/Users/path/to/Slic3r/slic3r.pl', '--info', '/Users/path/to/Desktop/STL_Files/GEAR.stl']
```

This can then further be used with Popen

```
p1=Popen(mac_arg)
```

**Shlex** main adavantage is that you dont need to worry about the commands , it will always split them in a manner accepted by Popen