# How to change directories in Python?

Tags: python, cd, os.system

I need to change the directory in the cmd with the command `cd`.
For example `cd users/desktop`. But when I run the script, nothing happens.

I have already tried with the following commands:

- `os.chdir("cd Documents/archive")`
- `os.system("cd Documents/archive")`

but neither of them works, just nothing happens.

How do you navigate in the directories with Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "cd" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-cd-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current directory using

```
os.getcwd()#gives you the directory in which you are in
```

os.chdir() takes the path not a command as argument.You can either use absolute or relative path
Assuming Documents is in your current directory
you can do.

```
os.chdir("./Documents/archive")
os.getcwd()#Gives you /home/user/Documents/archive
```