# cd using a python computed path?

Tags: python, bash, setuptools

Is there any Python/setuptools approach I could take to write a tool to change directory? There's a somewhat complicated path behind the scenes computed from a single parameter.

e.g., here's the closest I could come (in bash, untested):

`` alias mycd='function _mycd() { cd `myscript $1` };_mycd' ``

where `myscript` is something I can make available using `console_scripts` in `setuptools`.

I'm wondering if there was any way I could accomplish this in a self-contained manner, where for example, I don't edit a user's `.bash_profile` or save something in their `bin` or whatever. e.g., can I define an `alias` using setuptools?

Comment: The working directory is a property of an individual process, and cannot be changed by a script. `cd` is a shell built-in, and the current working directory of a process is inherited by its children. What is your actual use case?

Comment: Right... so I'm wondering if there's any way to create a "cd `myscript $1`" for the user? Power users could just create the alias themselves, I'm just wondering if I could automate that.

Comment: you might want to use the ```os``` package. [copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-directory-cd-in-python)?

Comment: Could you not do `alias mycd='function _mycd() { cd "$(/full/path/to/myscript $1)" };_mycd'`? Changed backticks to `$()`.  Couldn't figure out how to print those.  \` \` I get it now =D.

Comment: I'm afraid the best you can do is provide instructions on how to edit the user's relevant shell configuration files.

Comment: When you do, skip this odd alias no-op and just suggest  `mycd() { cd "$(myscript "$1")"; }`

Comment: I'm not convinced that there's no possibility given this context. E.g., when I'm picking my `conda` environment, I use `source activate myenv` where `source` is a script run in the current shell and could perhaps define an alias/function. I take it there's no way to hook into that, but it seems like there could be in principle at least. Maybe this isn't enough to clear the duplicate flag on this post though.