# How to change the directory of Linux in python script?

Tags: python, linux

Currently, I am using a python script to run commands in Linux shell. When I change the directory it doesn't seem to work (when I ran the command `ls` it listed files of the initial directory). I want to change the directory to the desktop.
My Code:

```
import os
os.popen("cd Desktop")
d = os.popen("ls")
x = d.read()
print (x)
```

Comment: Try [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Comment: Each time you execute `os.popen()` it is running the specified command in another process. So it does not affect your python process. Think of it as opening a terminal window and typing the command, then closing that window. The next `os.popen()` is not affected by the previous one.

Comment: `d = os.popen("cd Desktop && ls")` or `d = os.popen("ls ./Desktop")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change directory (cd) in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/608639), [How to change the working directory for a shell script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42617/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to use the `subprocess` module. It has a nicer API and does accept a keyword for this:

```
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.call("ls -ll", cwd='/tmp', shell=True)
```

Comment: Though maybe avoid the `shell=True` too. You'll need to split the command into a list yourself then `sp.call(['ls', '-ll'], cwd='/tmp')` -- see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess ... and while we are at it, probably prefer `check_call` or `subprocess.run(..., check=True)` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably the simplest solution is to do here is to use `os.chdir`. Below is an example

```
In[6]: os.listdir()
Out[6]: 
['.flask-env',
 'mydb_app',
'requirements.txt',
 '.idea',
 'sample_file_auth.py',
 'login_app']
In[7]: os.chdir('/home/rbhanot/tools')
In[8]: os.listdir()
Out[8]: ['miniconda3', 'nvim']
```