# How do I create a file inside a directory that I created?

Tags: python

I want to create a directory and then create some files in that directory.

I have already created a directory like so:

```py
if not os.path.exists("output"):
    os.mkdir("output")
```

How can I now access this directory and create some files using something like this `open("foo.txt", "w")`?

Comment: If you want to _change directory_ (go inside your newly create `output`) and create your files: [how do I cd in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-directory-cd-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend the directory name to your filename:

```py
with open('output/foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('some content')
```