# linux command using python to go under a specific folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell, command

Hello everyone : I have only one folder under my current directory and I want to go to it by running "cd $(ls)".
So I write this code

```
import os
os.system("cd $(ls)")
```

But this did not work for me . Anyone can help to write python syntax to go under the only available folder.
PS : the name of the folder is changeable that's why I want to use "cd $(ls)"

Comment: Maybe it did change directory but you don’t know because the `system()` process finished and returned.

Comment: Why do you want to use cd? If you make a system call with os then only that system call will have the changed working directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the working directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

The OS module has some utility functions to achieve what you want to do.

- `os.listdir()`: return a list with all files/directories inside the current working directory
- `os.chdir(path)`: changes your working directory

So, you could apply these like:

```py
os.chdir(os.listdir()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not obvious if by "go to it" you mean "change current directory for the remaining part of script code" or "change directory to be in **after** the script exits". If the later, you won't be able to do it - `os.system` starts a subshell, and changes of current directory in a subshell are not propagated to the parent shell. If the former, you should just use:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir(glob.glob('*')[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

`os.chdir(os.listdir('.')[0])`

Although `os.system("cd %(ls))` is correctly working in your shell it will not change the current working directory of your running python interpreter, because `os.system()` is using a separate shell instance that will be destroyed directly after the execution of the `cd` shell command.

Double check by executing `os.getcwd()` before and after (`os.getcwd()` returns the current working directory of your python interpreter).