# How to run a shell command in parallel to another command in python?

Tags: python, shell

*I want to run a shell command in python. In shell i am doing something like this*

```
cd project_name
ls
```

*output: app1 app2*

```
cd app1
```

*I want to do the same thing in python with os module*

```
import os
os.system('cd project_name') #It goes into the folder project_name but when i run ls command it is showing same path.
os.system('ls')
os.sytem('cd app1') # No such file or directory
```

*Please tell me how i can i do the same. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I change the working directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-in-python)

Comment: Why change the directory and why use the shell for things done in python? `os.listdir("project_name")` does the first two things.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you run os.system() you create a new subshell that is seperate from an previous os.system() calls.

If you want to run multiple commands you can string them together with

```
os.system("cd projectname && ls && cd app1")
```

Alternatively you can change directory in the subshell with

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track of paths in local variables and use them as needed. `pathlib` offers a convenient wrapper class for this.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> project_path = Path("project_name")
>>> project_path
PosixPath('project_name')
>>> str(project_path)
'project_name'
```

You can list

```
>>> print(list(project_path.iterdir()))
[PosixPath('project_name/app1'), PosixPath('project_name/app2')]
```

And make subpaths

```
>>> app1_path = project_path.joinpath("app1")
>>> app1_path
PosixPath('project_name/app1')
>>> str(app1_path)
'project_name/app1'
```

You can still run commands with `os.system` (notice the semicolon separating two commands)

```
>>> import os
>>> rc = os.system(f"cd {app1_path};ls")
foo  some_file
```

or use the subprocess module which allows you to specifiy current working directory

```
>>> import subprocess as subp
>>> rc = subp.run("ls", shell=True, cwd=app1_path)
foo  some_file
```

Code that unilaterally changes path can be hard to read. And its easy to get lost and do work in the wrong directory.