# Navigating to the current drive's root with Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, navigation

I'm looking for a way to get to the CWD's drive root no matter what the drive's volume letter is.

For example... say the program is on a drive (HDD's, SSD's, VHD's, etc.), I want to be able to go to the current drive's root. So basically, I want to change my CWD to the drive root no matter what the volume letter is.

I know that this says "Show what you've tried". The thing is, I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Ever heard of the `/` (Root) slash. Following this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/431715/9741277 should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Hope I'm up to date with python, but is mandatory that you use os lib. Then you can easily filter with regex.