# Launching a python script from a different directory

Tags: python, macos, shell

My main issue is that I'm trying to launch a Python script (I used `#!/usr/local/bin/python3` at the top, changed it to .command file, and made sure to run `chmod +x`) which uses a module (ezsheets) that references a specific folder for authentication, but I can't get it to automatically run as when I launch the script it references the home folder.

More specifically, I have a script in a folder called spreadsheets, and inside that folder I have the appropriate Google account permissions file. I store all my spreadsheet altering files in there as it seems EZsheets requires that in order to verify authentication.

However, when I run it as a .command file, I believe the issue is that it opens my Terminal in the home folder and then runs the script, and I get the following error:

```
    raise EZSheetsException(
ezsheets.EZSheetsException: Can't find credentials file at /Users/myusername/credentials-sheets.json
```

It can't find it, because that's located in `/username/documents/spreadsheets`.

When I am in the right directory in terminal and run the file manually, it works just fine.

Ideally I'd like to be able to launch this script from `/spreadsheets` and leave all my spreadsheet scripts in there as that has the permission file that I've already authenticated - is there any way to launch the script that executes starting from `/username/documents/spreadsheets` instead of the default home folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used ezsheets or .command files, but it looks like you just need to [change the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/431684/4518341):

```
import os

os.chdir('/username/documents/spreadsheets')
```

Comment: Yes, you're exactly right! I put that at the top of my script file to redirect the directory and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code below explains some path handling techniques that could be useful.

```py
import os

# At start the current path is where you execute the script,
# and not where the script is saved.
current_path = os.getcwd()
print(f"You are now in {current_path}")

# So get the path of the directory where the script actualy is.
script_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(f"The script {__file__} is stored in {script_path}")

# Or the path to the spreadsheets.
spreadsheets_path = "/username/documents/spreadsheets"

# Now change the current path.
os.chdir(script_path)

# And check that it is correct.
current_path = os.getcwd()
print(f"You are now in {current_path}")
```

Comment: Yup, putting the os.chdir at the top did exactly what I needed. Thanks!