# How do I open a csv file using VS python Jupiter cells

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, junit-jupiter

I have been trying to set The Desktop as my working Directory, so I can load a csv

```
import os
path="/Users/HOME/Desktop"
os.getcwd()
```

It returns
`/`

using pandas library I'm failing to use

```
DF =  pd.read_csv("filename", "mode")
```

Comment: Please include some more information in which way you are failing to use `read_csv`. What did you enter as filename and mode? What error did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

You did not actually change the working directory, you merely assigned a path to a variable. You need to invoke `os.chdir()` with that path (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/431715/14015737):

```
import os
path="/Users/HOME/Desktop"
os.chdir(path)
os.getcwd()
```

This should return the path.

In order to then read your `.csv` file that is located there (e.g. `/Users/HOME/Desktop/test.csv`) you can call `read_csv()` without a path. Full example:

```
import os
import pandas 

path='/Users/HOME/Desktop'
os.chdir(path)

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: With the new specified path. I should be able to open any files in that working directory?

Comment: Well as long as you have the proper access rights and no other program has locked the file, yes, you should be able to open it.