# Run .sh script from python from specific folder

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I am trying to run a .sh script from python.

I saw that this can be done in various ways such as:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["./test.sh"])
```

or

```
import os 

os.system("sh test.sh")
```

However this assumes that test.sh is in the same folder where you are running the script from. What if I want to run the .sh which is in a specific folder?

I tried the following but with no luck:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["cd ~/ros_ws", "./intera.sh"])
```

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["cd ~/ros_ws", "./intera.sh"], shell=True)
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent of shell 'cd' command to change the working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431684/equivalent-of-shell-cd-command-to-change-the-working-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subprocess.call` has an `cwd` function argument (change working directory)

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(["./intera.sh"], cwd="~/ros_ws")
```